# Variable in array key

Tags: php, arrays

Have array $data with keys like checkout_en, checkout_ru
and have var $lang with two variants ru and en.

How can i make smht like this $data['checkout_$lang'] to make key checkout_en or checkout_ru depends on $lang var value.

Thank you!

my code

```
$msg = '"buttons": [
            {
              "block_names": ["'.$settings['checkout_block_name'].'"],
              "type":"show_block",
              "title":"'.$settings["checkout_$settings['user_lang']"].'"
            }';
```

Comment: try `$data['checkout_' . $lang]`

Comment: Can you give the sample of the both array variables

Comment: Or `$data["checkout_$lang"]` Note use of double quotes, not single as you have in the question.

Comment: $data['checkout_'.$lang]   @ZainFarooq you need to remove last quote

Comment: @ParthShah Yes. You were right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in my case:

```
   {
     "block_names": ["$settings[start_block_name]"],
     "type":"show_block",
     "title":"'.$settings["back_to_shop_$settings[user_lang]"].'"
    }
```

Thanx:)

Answer (score 2):

Just simple concatenate:

```
 $data['checkout_' . $lang]
```